# Minimize function subject to constraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a constrained optimization problem using 
`cipy.optimize.minimize` but so far had no success.

Specifically I want to minimize the objective function over `y1` and `y2`:

```
f(y1,y2)=(x1(y1,y2)-x1)^2+(x2(y1,y2)-x2)^2
```

Subject to the constraint:

```
y1*y2>0
```

The goal is to find the values of `y1` and `y2` for different pairs of `x1` and `x2`.

This is what i have so far

```
def f(x1,x2):
    k=(x1(y1,y2)-x1)^2+(x2(y1,y2)-x2)^2
    return k
```

But i am not sure how to set up the function holding the aforementioned constraint:

```
def constraint(x):
    ....
```

Once i have the constraint is the following syntax correct?

```
optimize.minimize(f, np.array([0, 0]), method="SLSQP",
                  constraints={"fun": constraint, "type": "ineq"})
```

I am new in Python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The minimize docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#defining-linear-constraints) deal specifically with adding linear/nonlinear constraints to a minimization problem, have you tried using the built-in `constraint` objects?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message. I tried several things but they do not work. The problem is that I am not fluent with the syntax. If you have any ideas of how I could code this I would be grateful.

Comment: I posted an answer for the constraint part. I don't understand your function though, so I used an example. If you can specify it better, I can update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For constraints. From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

> Equality constraint means that the constraint function result is to be zero whereas inequality means that it is to be non-negative. Note that COBYLA only supports inequality constraints.

Therefore, your constraint is simply a function that must be non-negative. In your case:

```
def constraint(y):
    return y[0] * y[1]
```

Note that the function must input a vector. e.g.:

```
def f(x):
    x1, x2 = x
    return x1**2 + x2**2
```

**EDIT** Using a function that tries to fit calculated vs. observed data.

```
def calculated_x(y):
    """ example """
    y1, y2 = y
    x1 = 0.5 + 0.2 * y1 + 0.3 * y2
    x2 = 0.4 + 0.1 * y1 + 0.3 * y2

def f(y, x1, x2):
    x1_calc, x2_calc = calculated_x(y)
    return (x1- x1_calc)**2 + (x2 - x2_calc)**2

m = minimize(f, [0,0], args=(3,2), constraints=({'fun': lambda y: y[0] * y[1], 'type': 'ineq'},))
print(m)
>> array([3, 1.999999])
```

You can also build a function based on your minimization (example above):

```
def minimize_y(x1, x2):
    # note that x1 and x2 become arguments
    m = minimize(f, [0,0], args=(x1,x2), constraints=({'fun': lambda y: y[0] * y[1], 'type': 'ineq'},)
    return m.x
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I edited my question but i am not sure what is not clear?

Comment: What are x1 and x2? in python x1(y1, y2) means x1 as a function of y1 and y2, and x1[y1, y2] means x1 in position y1, y2-

Comment: x1 and x2 are user inputs. Based on these values and the constraint I would like to find y1 and y2.

Comment: and what is the difference between x1(y1, y2) and x1? Can you post an example of what our `f` will give for a given input x1, x2, y1, y2?

Comment: Yes, if x1=0.2 and x2=2.8, then y1=0.1221 and y2=0.2273

Comment: Ok, I don't understand the how you got from x1 and x2 to y1 and y2 (and what is the result of f). Hopefully the example I added can illustrate itself?

Comment: Ok , now I understand what you are trying to achieve. I don't understand the explicit functions for the alphas though. I'm posting an example (simply replace `calculate_x` with the correct function)